# How to give two links for mobile and tablet in webview?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-widget

I have two links,for eg: say facebook.com and m.facebook.com.If it's android mobile, i want to

open m.facebook.com.If it's android tablet,i want to open facebook.com link.I want to do in

webview.How it is possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is another solution with use of `simple flag`:

Set a boolean value in a specific value file like say (`res/values-xlarge/`):

```
<resources>
    <bool name="isTabletDevice">true</bool>
</resources>
```

Then, in the "standard" value file like say (`res/values/`):

```
<resources>
    <bool name="isTabletDevice">false</bool>
</resources>
```

Then from your `activity`, fetch this `flag value` to check `device type` :

```
boolean tabletDeviceSize = getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.isTabletDevice);
if (tabletDeviceSize) {
    //use tablet link
} else {
    //use mobile link
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this it might help you.

```
public static boolean isTablet(Context context) {
    boolean xlarge = ((context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == 4);
    boolean large = ((context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE);
    return (xlarge || large);
}

if(isTablet(context)) {
    //use tablet link
}
else {
    //use mobile link.
}
```